# How to setup properties in a ViewModel that gets and sets values from a list of models?

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding

I am still fairly new to MVVM and need some guidance.

I have setup the below MVVM and this works fine when using:

```
private Model model = new Model();
```

However, I actually want to have a collection of the models.

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
```

What I can't quite figure out right now is how to get the properties to return for instance the title of the bound / selected model.

I can't specify an index because I don't know the indexes yet. I'm thinking in the View, I'll add a hidden combobox and when the window is loaded, create a new model, and select the highest index. But how do I ensure the right property is returned and how to code that?

**CURRENT SETUP**

**View**

The view is binded to the ViewModel as follows.

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <this:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

**ViewModel**

The ViewModel is composed of two classes. A parent class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and the ViewModel for the current View.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Framework
{
    public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Events
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion

        #region Implementation
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

```
using Framework;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Windows;

namespace ESL_Master_Suite.Components.Core.Courses
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Courses.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Courses : Window
    {
        public Courses()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    class ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Model> models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        //private Model model = new Model();

        #region Fields
        bool skipUpdating = false;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return model.title;
            }
            set
            {
                model.title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Model / Model_Weeks**

The Model and sub-models are shown below.

```
   class Model
    {
        public string title;
        
        public ObservableCollection<Model_Weeks> weeks = new ObservableCollection<Model_Weeks>();
    }

    class Model_Weeks
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "topic")]
        public int topic { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of playing I've come up with the following solution. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but it seems to work.

I have two ViewModels and also two Models.

**Courses_ViewModel**

```
class Courses_ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public Courses_Model courses_Model;
        public ObservableCollection<Course_ViewModel> course_ViewModels { get; set; }

        public Courses_ViewModel()
        {
            //Deserialize and assign Parent Model to Local Variable
            courses_Model = new Courses_Model();

            //Initialise ChildModel List
            course_ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<Course_ViewModel>();

            //Create ChildViewModels and Add to List
            foreach (Course_Model course in courses_Model.course_Models)
            {
                course_ViewModels.Add(new Course_ViewModel(course));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Course_ViewModel**

```
class Course_ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public Course_Model course_Model { get; set; }

        public Course_ViewModel(Course_Model model)
        {
            course_Model = model;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return course_Model.title;
            }
            set
            {
                course_Model.title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Models**

```
class Courses_Model
    {
        //List of courses
        public List<Course_Model> course_Models { get; set; }

        public Courses_Model()
        {
            //Initialise course_Models List
            course_Models = new List<Course_Model>();

            //Create courses and add to list
            course_Models.Add(new Course_Model { title = "L1" });
            course_Models.Add(new Course_Model { title = "L2" });
            course_Models.Add(new Course_Model { title = "L3" });
            course_Models.Add(new Course_Model { title = "L4" });
            course_Models.Add(new Course_Model { title = "L5" });
        }
    }

    class Course_Model
    {
        public string title;
    }
```